# How to perform a vectorized division in Julia?

Tags: julia

given a multi-dimensional array of 252×3 Array{Float64,2}, why can't I do something Python-esque like:

`normalized_data = vals / vals[1,:]` to have every element divided by the 1st item in its respective column.  This works in Python (albeit with `vals[0,:]` in the denominator).  In Julia, I had to use:

`normalized_data = [(vals[:,1] / vals[1,1]) (vals[:,2] / vals[1,2])  (vals[:,3] / vals[1,3])]`

This seems really limiting and isn't generic to work no matter how many columns of data I have!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can.

```
normalized_data = vals ./ vals[1,:]
```

or even better, if `normalized_data` is already allocated:

```
normalized_data .= vals ./ vals[1,:]
```

(Edit: For v0.5 or higher, it needs to be `vals ./ vals[1,:].'` due to the dropped dimensions. See comments)

will be allocation-free. This form of vectorization syntax is partially derived from MATLAB. I would suggest looking through the manual. One place to look if you're just starting is the differences from other languages:

http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/noteworthy-differences/

For more on broadcasting and understanding what we gain by making the `.` explicit, see the follow blog post:

http://julialang.org/blog/2017/01/moredots

Essentially, because the `.`'s are explicit, the parser can fuse the expressions and make it much more efficient than doing "vectorized" computing a la NumPy (or at least, it will always be as efficient as possible, instead of sometimes being efficient due to compiler magic).

Comment: Remember that `val[1, :]` now gets turned into a `Vector`, so you need `vals ./ vals[1,:]'` on versions >=0.5.

Comment: Since `'` is conjugate transposition, it should be `vals ./ vals[1,:].'` in general.

Comment: Apologies to Chris--I should have been specific with what version of Julia I am using (v 5.0).  I've not tried it but I'm sure his dot division example works in versions < 5.0 and so will accept that.  What DID work for me were suggestions from both DNF and tim.  Thanks all!

Comment: Instead of transposing, I find it much more readable to just keep the dimension within the indexing expression directly: `vals ./ vals[1:1, :]`.